# asp.net mvc authorize attribute redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my application I have made a custom Attribute like this

```
public class AdminAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!isAuthorized || Auth.CurrentAdminUser == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return (SuperAdmin.Get(Auth.CurrentAdminUser.Id) != null) ? true : false;
        }
    }
}
```

It is working fine, but what I want is to do a redirect based on if the user is not logged in then take to log in page and if the user is logged in but is not a super admin take him to not authorize page.

What happens now is that all the unauthorized stuff is redirected to this page through web.config file,

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Site/NotAuthorize" timeout="2880" />
  <!-- this is where we can set up that if you are not authenticated, where should you go then?-->
</authentication>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: u can override HandleUnauthorizedRequest in your attirubute class to redirect it

Comment: Can't I use httpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Admin"); in this function?

Comment: You can create custom action filter attribute

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should override `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);

    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "xxx", action = "xxx", area = "" }));
}
```

Comment: Or simply `filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Site/NotAuthorize");`.